# WP_Query doesn't accept Category ID

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I am trying to make a Query wich only shows images, but I have the problem that it doesn't work with the custom post types category ID.

Here my code:

```
$catid = get_term_by( 'name', $name, $taxonomy );
$catid = $catid->term_id;



$args_query = array(
'cat' => &catid,
'posts_per_page' => 6, 
'post_type' => 'video',
'hide_empty' => 1
);

$query= new WP_Query( $args_query );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
 while($query->have_posts()) { 
    $query->the_post(); 
    ?><?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  
        the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
    } else {
        echo '<p>this post does not have a featured image</p>';
    }
}
} else {
echo '<p>No post images found</p>';
}
```

Anybody knows a fix for that problem?

By the way I am using a Shortcode to get $name and $taxonomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your category is custom taxonomy you'll have to use tax_query in you `WP_Query()`.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

I guess it's a typo that you have `&catid` instead of `$catid`.

Edit:
Something like:

```
$args_query = array(
'posts_per_page' => 6, 
'post_type' => 'video',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $catid
        )
     )
);
```

Note: Check for typos since I have not tried or tested this.

Comment: I already saw that with the &... But can you explain what field and terms mean please

Comment: Added the code, check if that's what you need.

Comment: It only shows the whole post type and not the category members :/

Comment: You need to debug. Print values of `$taxonomy`, `$catid`. And also WP_Query after running query. Also check for syntax mistakes.

Comment: Cat ID: 479 Taxonomy: videos_categories Query: Doesn't show up

Comment: Query shows all post as it should

Comment: Query I wrote works for me. Are you using same query?

Comment: Yes and it shows up with print_r

Comment: You need to debug. Check SQL query in WP_Query

Comment: SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID = 22 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC

Comment: That's your page query, not custom query you're writing.

Comment: How do I display the custom query?

Comment: print_r($query);

Comment: Try edited code now.